# IE.Document.getElementsByName("name").Value = "Value" not working

Tags: excel, vba

When I try and do this, it throws a number of errors at me depending on other bits of my code, such as the method is not associated with that object or an unspecified error.

I am trying to go down a list of Excel cells with strings and use a web form to search for those strings.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Sub YSF_automation()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "URL"

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.getElementsByName("ElementName")(0).Value = "test"

End Sub
```

Comment: without seeing any of your code, this is the best i have.. change the code to `IE.Document.getElementsByName(“name”)(0).Value = “Value”`

Comment: The IE.Document.getElementsByName(“name”) returns a collection of elements not a single element so you cannot set it's value like that. Try what @user1 has suggested. Remember the index in the collection will start from 0 so change it as per your requirement.

Comment: This is the HTML of the text box I am trying to write to: <input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox" name="caseNumber">.

Comment: @user1 example should work then .... you already have the code in the program that you posted

Comment: Well I've modified it since, attempting to get it it to work. It throws a 'Method "Document" of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed' error.

Comment: Show us your variable declaration for IE and DOCUMENT

Comment: You are getting the error probably because you defined the variables inappropriately

Comment: It is simply `DIM IE As Object`. Apologies for being vague, I'm extremely inexperienced with VBA. Essentially, I am just googling for methods, rampantly.

Comment: @YaYaYaYaYaYa ,There is nothing wrong with being extremely inexperienced. Anyways, reveal the link (if that is not a problem) to get direct help. Otherwise any link that resembles the one you are working with.

Comment: What web page are you trying to automate?  Can you give us an address?

Comment: change the wait loop to this   `While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
Option Explicit

Dim IE as Object

Sub YSF_automation()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "URL"

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

set document = IE.document
with document
    .getElementsByName("ElementName")(0).value="test"
end with
End Sub
```